# Need Help Designing a toggle power and timer delay circuit

Tags: relay, timer, delay

I need help designing a circuit that will momentarily toggle motor power off, while it turns a set of battery relays on for 3 min.

After 3 min it toggles motor power off while it then turns battery relays OFF for 3 min.

Then the cycle repeats.

A delay timer from Amazon can do this but not toggle power on/off.  If I actuate the relays with motor power on, they tend to burn out or stick.  I'm not sure how to build the power toggle on/off into the delay timer circuit.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: - It sounds like the motor will be off for both cycles. Can you explain better what will happen in every part of the cycle? also, how is the motor controlled by the circuit: through a relay or another method?

Comment: Please provide data sheet links to the motor, battery and relay. Next, show schematically how the shamazon part can be used (even if it doesn't provide full functionality). The power source needs clarification and details.